# Find Geo and additional fields via AWS amplify and ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, geo, aws-amplify

In the documentation of AWS amplify it's defined how you can search for a Geo location only by creating a custom resolver:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql?sdk=js#add-a-custom-resolver-that-targets-a-dynamodb-table-from-model

But how is it possible to find this location in combination with any other query filter, for example like a certain name. So find everybody with name X in location X.

I have got this template:

```
"version": "2017-02-28",
"operation": "GET",
"path": "$indexPath.toLowerCase()",
"params": {
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    { match : { "name": $ctx.args.params.name }},
                ],
                "filter" : {
                    "geo_distance" : {
                        "distance" : "${distance}km",
                        "location" : $util.toJson($ctx.args.location)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

with this schema:

```
input paramsStringFilterInput {
  ne: String
  eq: String
  match: String
  matchPhrase: String
  matchPhrasePrefix: String
  multiMatch: String
  exists: Boolean
  wildcard: String
  regexp: String
}

input ParamsInput {
  name: paramsStringFilterInput
  monday: Boolean
}

type ZVLConnection {
  items: [ZVL]
  total: Int
  nextToken: String
}

type Query {
  nearbyZVL(params: ParamsInput, location: LocationInput!, km: Int): ZVLConnection
}
```

I getting this error with this query:

```
query getProfiles{
  nearbyZVL(
    location: { 
        lat:51.848388,
      lon: 5.447252
    },
    km: 12,
    params:{
      name: { match: "Ramon" }
    }

  ){
    total,
    items {   
      id
      name
    }

  }

}

{
  "data": {
    "nearbyZVL": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "nearbyZVL"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Unable to parse the JSON document: 'Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (String)\"\n{\n    \"version\": \"2017-02-28\",\n    \"operation\": \"GET\",\n    \"path\": \"/zorgverlener/doc/_search\",\n    \"params\": {\n        \"body\": {\n            \"query\": {\n                \"bool\" : {\n                    \"must\" : [\n                        { match : { \"name\": Ramon }},\n                    ],\n                    \"filter\" : {\n                        \"geo_distance\" : {\n                            \"distance\" : \"12km\",\n                            \"location\" : {\"lat\":51.848388,\"lon\":5.447252}\n            \"[truncated 86 chars]; line: 11, column: 28]'"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do the same thing with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

@ramon hey dude so I maned to get it working with various search filters:

Schema:

```
type Query {
  nearByEvents(filter: SearchEventsNearbyInput, sort: SearchNearbyEventsSortInput, limit: Int, nextToken: Int): EventConnection
}
```

Resolvers:

```
set( $indexPath = "/event/doc/_search" )
#set( $distance = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.filter.km, 200) )
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "GET",
    "path": "$indexPath.toLowerCase()",
    "params": {
        "body": {
            "from": #if( $context.args.nextToken ) $context.args.nextToken #else 0 #end,
            "size": #if( $context.args.limit ) $context.args.limit #else 20 #end,
            "sort":       #if( $context.args.sort )
            [#if( !$util.isNullOrEmpty($context.args.sort.field) && !$util.isNullOrEmpty($context.args.sort.direction) )
            {
                "$context.args.sort.field": {
                    "order": "$context.args.sort.direction"
                }
            }
            #end, "_doc"]
                #else
                    []
                #end,
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "range": {
                        "dateTime": {
                            "gte": $ctx.args.filter.startDate,
                            "lt": $ctx.args.filter.endDate
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    #if( $context.args.filter.categories.size() > 0 )
                    "should": [
                    #foreach( $category in $ctx.args.filter.categories )
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "categories": "$category"
                            }
                        }
                        #if( $foreach.hasNext ),
                        #end
                    #end
                    ], 
                    "minimum_should_match": 2
                    , #end
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance" :"${distance}km",
                            "distance_type": "plane",
                            "location": $util.toJson($ctx.args.filter.location)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

.

```
#set( $items = [] )
#foreach( $entry in $context.result.hits.hits )
  #if( !$foreach.hasNext )
    #set( $nextToken = "$entry.sort.get(0)" )
  #end
  $util.qr($items.add($entry.get("_source")))
#end
$util.toJson({
  "items": $items,
  "total": $ctx.result.hits.total,
  "nextToken": $nextToken
})
```

Then I was able to query with filters, sorting and limits whilst still using geo distance

Hope this helps!